# Is it ok for a javascript variable to be 2Mb long?

Tags: javascript, memory-efficient

I have a list of all articles in NY Times from its beginning and want have an instant access to all of them without connecting to external database, so my solution is holding it in one variable. But isn't that a bad practice in terms of efficiency?

Comment: What kind of variable? Big string? Array with one entry per article?

Comment: Yes, it's a terrible idea. How do you think performance will be if you start to do searches or manipulate the variable? Why would you do this only using javascript? What is wrong with a database? And have you considered php and flat-file storage?

Comment: Are we back in 1990? (Just kidding about the "2Mb".)

Comment: @OptimusCrime: A proper in-memory data structure can be searched and manipulated much easier then a remote database (works offline, no need for any server-side). A 2MB Javascript data file can be cached by browsers, making reloads very fast as well.

Comment: @Thilo : Yes that is true, but if he want to use this variable, as I assume he will, the performance will be terrible compared to having a backend script. To answer the question again, having this variable is "ok", but considering how difficult this will make everything else, I would rather do it another way.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that the memory usage is any problem - modern browser games for example probably use an order of magnitude more memory.

I would worry more about the data structure and the operations you intend to run on it.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of application are you writing?
It would properbly be a better idea to create a local database and store the articles there and then create a sync task that pulls only the articles that are of a later date than the previous sync task and save them to the local db.
It all depends on what kind of application you are writing of course

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into using [HTML5 Local Storage](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/) to store this variable or it's contents.  This way you're keeping things client-side as you wish whilst also storing the data properly.